# Tag synonym: webfilter web-filtering

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Hope this is the right place for such things.. is there an easier way to propose a synonym?

Also synonyms of contentfilter?

Comment: The synonym system is borked because the rules are setup for StackOverflow (The favorite SE site; the rest of us are just red-headed step children) where they have 20 times as many people as any other SE Site. Posting here is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

All done, merged and synonym created.